Can the mechanism behind changes in protein expression be inferred by the timing of those changes?
My question relates to the timing of protein expression changes, and whether there is a literature-based consensus as to how long changes in protein generally take.
For example, if protein changes 24h after a treatment, then its expression may be due to release of a translational block, whereas if a protein is expressed 72h after a treatment then it is being transcribed and translated rather than just the latter.
Or is this something that is too variable to draw general conclusions on?
Thanks in advance

I made some edits that I think clarify without changing meaning but feel free to edit again if that's wrong. "Gene expression" is a pretty broad term but I think you're asking about changes in protein.

NO. Science is about experiments to test hypotheses. Temporal associations are merely the basis for such hypothesis. And whenever zi hear the word “consensus” I reach for my  bro…  …omstick.
